# Binary Search Tree error in main

Tags: java, runtime-error, binary-search-tree

```
import linearstructures.*;
import non_lineardatastructures.*;
import workers.*;
import binarynodes.*;
import linearnodes.*;
import dataobjects.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    public static BinarySearchTree tree;
    public static int seqNum;
    public static double pay;
    public static Employee name;
    Node front;
    Node rear;


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int menu;
        CQueue queue = new CQueue(); 
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();

        do{ 
            System.out.println("\f\f");
            System.out.println("1. Construct an Empty Queue and Binary Tree");
            System.out.println("2. Populate Queue with Employees and Part-Timers");
            System.out.println("3. List all objects in Queue");
            System.out.println("4. Edit an Object in Queue");
            System.out.println("5. Populate BST with Queue objects");
            System.out.println("6. Search BST by surname");
            System.out.println("7. List BST In-Order");
            System.out.println("8. Exit menu");
            System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");

            menu=input.nextInt();
            switch(menu){
                case 1:queue = new CQueue(); tree = new BinarySearchTree();System.out.println("A new Queue and BST have been constructed!");break;
                case 2:System.out.println("Do you want to create an Employee or a Part-Timer?");
                System.out.println("Enter e or p");
                String choice=input.next();
                if(choice.equals("e")){

                    Employee name=new Employee();
                    System.out.println("Enter surname:");
                    String surname=input.next();
                    name.setSurname(surname);

                    System.out.println("Enter seqNum:");
                    seqNum=input.nextInt();
                    name.setSeq(seqNum);
                    System.out.println("Enter pay:");
                    pay=input.nextDouble();
                    name.setPay(pay);
                    queue.put(name);
                    System.out.println("A new Employee has been created!");
                }
                else if(choice.equals("p")){

                    PartTimer pt=new  PartTimer();
                    System.out.println("Enter surname:");
                    String surname2=input.next();
                    pt.setSurname(surname2);

                    System.out.println("Enter seqNum:");
                    int seqNum=input.nextInt();
                    pt.setSeq(seqNum);
                    System.out.println("Enter pay:");
                    double pay=input.nextDouble();
                    pt.setPay(pay);
                    System.out.println("Enter hours worked:");
                    int hours=input.nextInt();
                    pt.setHours(hours);
                    queue.put(pt);
                    System.out.println("A new Part-Timer has been created!");
                }
                else System.out.println("Enter a valid choice!");break;
                case 3:queue.listAll();break;
                case 4:System.out.println("Enter surname:");
                String surname3=input.next();


                if(queue!=null){

                    if((queue.searchKey(surname3))!=null){
                        queue.editObject(surname3);
                        queue.listAll();
                    }
                }else System.out.print("empty");break;
                case 5: tree.populateFromQueue(queue);break;
                case 6:System.out.println("Enter surname:");
                String surname4=input.next();
                tree.search(surname4);break;
                case 7: tree.inorderBST();break;
                case 8:break;
                default: System.out.print("Enter a valid choice!");
            }
            System.out.println("Press any key to continue..");
            String cont=input.next();
        }while(menu!=8);
    }   




}
```

```java
package non_lineardatastructures;
import linearstructures.*;
import binarynodes.*;
import workers.*;
import linearnodes.*;
import dataobjects.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BinarySearchTree
{
    public static BNode root;
    //public BNode newNode;
    public Employee temp=new Employee();


    public BinarySearchTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    // Worksheet 7 - Part 5a

    protected BNode insertB(BNode root,BNode newNode) 
    {           
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = newNode;
        }
        else if (newNode.obj.getKey().compareTo(root.obj.getKey())<0)
        {
            if (newNode.obj.getKey().compareTo(root.obj.getKey())>0)
            { 
               root.right= insertB(root.right,newNode);
            } 
        }
        return root;
    }

    public void insert(AnyClass newObj)
    {
        BNode temp=new BNode(newObj);
        root=insertB(root,temp);
    }

    private void inorder(BNode parent)
    {
        if (parent != null)
        {
            inorder(parent.left);

            inorder(parent.right);
        }
    }


    public void inorderBST ()
    {             
        recprint(root);
        System.out.println();
    }

    protected void recprint(BNode p)
    {
        if (p == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        recprint(p.left);
        System.out.print(p.obj.getData());
        recprint(p.right);
    }


    public AnyClass search(String key)
    {
        Employee temp2=new Employee();
        root.obj.getData();


        System.out.print(root.obj.getKey());
        if(root!=null)
        {         
            if((root.obj.getKey()).compareTo(key)==0)
            {
                System.out.print("Found");
                return root.obj;
            }
            else if((root.obj.getKey()).compareTo(key)>0)
            {
                return search(key);
            }
            else
            {    
                return search(key);
            }
        }
        else
        {     
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void populateFromQueue(CQueue que)
    {
        AnyClass obj;

        while(que.front!=null)
        {
            obj=que.serve();
            this.insert(obj);
        }

    }
}
```

This program creates a BST and a circular list. All functions working fine except list in order and search (located in bst class). No idea why these are not working but the work when there is only one element in the queue.

Comment: The code snippet is for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript btw.

Comment: What do you mean when you say not working? Any error/exception/wrong result etc?

Comment: basically displaying nothing @SMA

Answer (score 1):

**First: the search(String key) method:**

What would be correct:
Going through every node and check whether it's smaller or greater than the value you are searching for and the go to it's left/right node and continue this procedure (recursion!) until you find the correct value or a `null` value.

What you are doing: You take your `root` and compare it to your key. If it's correct, then everthing's just fine. If not you are calling the method again with the same parameters. The node you are comparing to has not changed so this results in an infinte loop.

In general searching for a value in a BST is almost the same procedure as inserting a new value. So after you've corrected your `instertB()` method you could easily copy and change it in order to work like a `search()` method.

And by the way:
You're never really using these two lines:

```
Employee temp2=new Employee();
root.obj.getData();
```

**Second: the insertB(...) method:**

I won't give you any solution for this (yet), because I wan't you to learn something. (but if you really don't understand what to do just leave a comment).
So I have just one question for you: *What happens if the value you try to insert is smaller than the root's value?*

Comment: so how i check each node ?

Comment: At first I would suggest you to care about your instertB() method.

Comment: im sorry im very new to java

Comment: Do you know how a BST is build? Smaller Nodes are on the left side and greater nodes on the right side

Comment: any ideas how i can fix this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98474/discussion-between-jibbow-and-chris).

Comment: so i basically did it the other way round .. i see thankyou!

Comment: wait im not understanding?